# しちゃいない meaning in this sentence.

Tags: translation

I came across the following sentence

不幸の手紙から、全然進歩しちゃいない

I'm not too sure what the しちゃいない means ( I know what the sentence means).

I know that ちゃ is a contraction of ては but in that grammar I've always seen it followed by 駄目、いけない or ならない. Is the いない just the negative of いる and can follow on since we had the て form (as well as は particle) of する？in which case I'm then not sure of the meaning of just しちゃ...

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know what the sentence means if you are unsure about the meaning of an important part of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

不幸の手紙から、全然進歩しちゃいない

・進歩する present form, positive
・進歩しない present form, negative

・進歩した perfect form, positive
・進歩してはいない perfect form, negative (denial of positive)

・進歩しちゃいない casual perfect form, negative
　(しては＋いない　→　しちゃ＋いない）

Comment: So is してはいない  the same as しなかった?

Comment: What's the difference between 進歩して**は**いない and 進歩していない?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the expression on Google and felt that it has less to do with 「しては+いけない」。People have been using this expression to describe unexpected contrasts.

「しちゃいない」＝「してはいない」 means the same thing as 「していない」, and 「は」is inserted to emphasize the state being described by the phrase 「していない」.

So in this case, the speaker of this sentence really wants to highlight the fact that there is no progress at all.