# What is the difference between してはいない and していない

Tags: conjugations

What is the difference between してはいない and していない?

**NOTE:** This post is inspired by [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44217/%e3%81%97%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-meaning-in-this-sentence), which touched upon this topic (though I never felt like a definitive or clear answer was provided).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"は" in this case is to restrict the extent. By restriction, you hint at something else beyond restriction such as:

- 学校を中退して働き始めたことを後悔してはいない（が、できれば卒業したかった）。
- 約束を忘れてはいない（けど、すぐに果たす気はない）。
- 彼は間違った事を言ってはいない（ちょっと表現に問題はあるけどね）。

If you say 後悔していない, 忘れていない or 言っていない, you just mean it.