# What is から doing in 不幸の手紙から, 全然進歩しちゃいない?

Tags: translation

From the first episode of Death Note:

> 不幸の手紙から, 全然進歩しちゃいない

This apparently means something like

> No better than chain letters.

**Questions:**

1. I know から usually means "from", but what function is から playing?
2. Why is 進歩しちゃいない used instead of 進歩していない? I know according to [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95860/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%af%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-and-%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84/95874#95874) that 進歩しちゃいない includes a (hidden) は in it, which "hints at something else beyond restriction". I'm not sure what this would mean in this context though. Does this hint that while this letter might not be better than a chain letter, it might be better than...something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is mostly a matter of translation. It still means *from*, or *compared with*. Consider another example: 人間は一万年前**から**進歩してない= *People have not changed **compared with/since** 10000 years ago*. The sentence could be translated as *(It) is no different from chain letters*.
2. It is certainly a version of してはいない, but the difference is rather subtle, 全然進歩して(い)ない sounds practically the same to me, simply しちゃいない being more colloquial. 
    That said, the presence of は can be considered as an emphasis. Or (not exclusively) it indicates the contrast with the common conception that the opposite is true (in the example, it **is** different from chain letters). For example, 人間は1万年前から進歩しちゃいない sounds more like the speaker assuming that generally it is believed that humans have changed a lot over 10000 years.

Comment: Do you think that 進歩しちゃいない also conveys something like "not the *slightest* bit better than chain letters" (versus 進歩していない which might merely mean "not better than chain letters")?

Comment: @George I think は（ちゃ） per se does not convey that meaning, but it is reasonable to think that は combined with 全然 works that way (i.e., emphasis).